# OS X: c++ xcode ncurses resize terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal, resize

with `ncurses.h`, i can create a c++ project in OS X.

Here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // resizeterm(50, 50);
    initscr();
    // resizeterm(50, 50);
    move(10, 10);
    printw("%c", 'x');
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it in the terminal:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -std=c++11 -lncurses main.o
```

Then I get an executable file: `a.out`.

Now if I type `./a.out` in the terminal, the terminal will will print `x` at the position (10, 10).

Now I want to change the size of the terminal. Meaning that when I run `./a.out`, I can immediately get a terminal with the size that I set. Google gave me a function: `resizeterm(int, int)`. But it doesn't work.

When I open a terminal, its size is 80 * 24 by default.
Then I execute `./a.out`, the size of the terminal isn't changed. It's always 80 * 24.

Comment: I believe `resizeterm` only works with X11 windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) [*responds*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#handle_resize) to window-resizing events, i.e., `SIGWINCH`.  It does *not* resize the terminal (see manual page for [`resizeterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html)).

[xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) and some other terminal emulators respond to an escape sequence which tells it to resize.  You can exercise that with the utility program [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html), e.g.,

```
resize -s 40 80
```

to make 40 rows of 80 columns.  On OSX, `Terminal.app` responds to this escape sequence.  `iTerm 2` does not.